# Custom marker with server imagen in mapkit swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

Its posible set a custom marker with images loaded by server in mapview iOS swift?  I jus found customs marker with local images

Comment: Yes, its possible. You can use custom annotation view. It can be loaded from an xib as well, add `UIImageView` in it and Use `AFNetworking`'s  or any other image caching mechanism `UIImageView` category, it'll load image from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

By marker, I'm assuming you are referring to and utilizing a `MKAnnotationView` (which is what Apple's pin views subclass from).

`MKAnnotationView` has an `.image` property, which you could set to any `UIImage`. You'd have to download the image first from server, then assign it to the annotation view.

It doesn't look like there is a way to link the `MKAnnotationView`'s image property directly to a remote URL without defining that behavior for yourself (and perhaps subclassing drawing code).